# Change SELECT DISTINCT to UPDATE DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server, update, distinct

How can I modify my `SELECT DISTINCT` query to an `UPDATE DISTINCT` query?

It is important that it only updates the distinct records, as there are multiple records associated with each [Finance_Project_Number] (due to CRUD operations). I only want to update a single record, as this will simply set in motion a different process of validating the data etc.

If there are multiple records collapsed into a single row as a result of the DISTINCT, any of these can be updated - it does not matter.

When I run my select query, I get a result of: 6 982:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [Finance_Project_Number]
FROM [InterfaceInfor].[dbo].[ProjectMaster]
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM [IMS].[dbo].[THEOPTION]  
        WHERE 
            [InterfaceInfor].[dbo].[ProjectMaster].[Finance_Project_Number] =
            [IMS].[dbo].[THEOPTION].[NAME]
    );
```

Here is my attempt at converting my query to a `DISTINCT UPDATE` query, but this updates 15 353 records:

```
UPDATE [InterfaceInfor].[dbo].[ProjectMaster]
SET 
    [Processing_Result_Text] = 'UNIQUE',
    [Processing_Result] = 0
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM [IMS].[dbo].[THEOPTION]  
        WHERE 
            [InterfaceInfor].[dbo].[ProjectMaster].[Finance_Project_Number] =
            [IMS].[dbo].[THEOPTION].[NAME]
    );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To just update an arbitrary one from each distinct group you could use

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Finance_Project_Number] 
                                       ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN,
                [Processing_Result_Text],
                [Processing_Result]
         FROM   [InterfaceInfor].[dbo].[ProjectMaster]
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM   [IMS].[dbo].[THEOPTION]
                            WHERE  [InterfaceInfor].[dbo].[ProjectMaster].[Finance_Project_Number] = [IMS].[dbo].[THEOPTION].[NAME]))
UPDATE T
SET    [Processing_Result_Text] = 'UNIQUE',
       [Processing_Result] = 0
WHERE  RN = 1;
```

If you decide there is some criteria by which the row to be updated should be selected after all simply change the `ORDER BY (SELECT 0)` accordingly so that the desired target row is ordered first - e.g. `ORDER BY DateInserted desc` would update the latest one as ordered by a column called DateInserted if such a column exists.

---

This uses a [common table expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) (CTE) because it is not permitted to reference ranking functions such as [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) directly in the `WHERE` clause. It is allowed to update data via common table expressions in the same circumstances as for [updatable views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187956.aspx) (basically the data being updated must be able to be mapped back straight forwardly to specific items in a single base table).

If you are not yet familiar with ranking functions you may well find `SELECT`-ing from the CTE first to be beneficial.

```
CREATE TABLE #TheOption(NAME VARCHAR(50));

CREATE TABLE #ProjectMaster
(
Finance_Project_Number VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Processing_Result_Text VARCHAR(50) NULL,
Processing_Result INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #ProjectMaster (Finance_Project_Number, Processing_Result_Text)
VALUES ('A00001', 'A'), 
       ('A00001', 'B'), 
       ('A00001', 'C'), 
       ('B99999', 'D'), 
       ('B99999', 'E'), 
       ('C47474', 'F'), 
       ('C47474', 'G');

INSERT INTO #TheOption (NAME) VALUES('C47474');


WITH T
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Finance_Project_Number 
                                       ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN,
                Finance_Project_Number,
                Processing_Result_Text,
                Processing_Result
         FROM   #ProjectMaster pm
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM   #TheOption opt
                            WHERE  pm.Finance_Project_Number =opt.NAME))
SELECT *
FROM T
ORDER BY Finance_Project_Number, RN;
```

Example results are below

[image]

The `C47474` rows are filtered out as they do exist in the other table so don't meet the `NOT EXISTS`, the remaining rows are grouped by `Finance_Project_Number` and assigned a sequential number within each group.

In this case the yellow rows would meet the `RN = 1` condition and be updated. However there is no guarantee exactly how these numbers will be assigned within each group unless you use a `ORDER BY` clause on an expression guaranteed to be unique. Without this it could potentially change even between successive executions of the same statement.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I try to do it other ways, with fancy joins and whatnot, I typically come back to something that is easy to wrap my head around, and, whatsmore, can test a sample of (replace the `UPDATE/SET` with a `SELECT`) before I execute.

```MSSQL
WITH UpdateData AS (
                    SELECT DISTINCT t.match, t.oldvalue, t2.newvalue
                    FROM origin t
                    JOIN newstuff t2 ON t.PK = t2.FK
                    WHERE t.Valid = 1 AND t2.Valid = 1 
                    )
UPDATE origin
SET origin.oldvalue=UpdateData.newvalue
FROM origin
     INNER JOIN UpdateData 
         ON UpdateData.match=origin.match
WHERE origin.Valid = 1
```

Some caveats:

- If you're trying to execute this as part of a larger script, keep in
  mind that you might need a semicolon before the `WITH`.
- I assume since I don't see this style in the wild, it's probably not
  so efficient.  I wouldn't make this part of production code, or use
  it on very large datasets.